# Linq Select if vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I have an dollar amount in my database column. I can get it to place the data in a column based on whether or not the amount is negative or positive, but it produces "0.00" in the False column. How do I get it to leave that column blank?

The code that I have is as follows.

```
Dim query = From t In ds.HNBSavings
                Order By t.Date Descending, t.Id Descending
                Select t.Id, t.Date, t.Desc, Debit = If(t.Amount >= 0, t.Amount, 0), Credit = If(t.Amount < 0, t.Amount, 0)

dgBank.ItemsSource = query.ToList()
```

So the results are 5.0000 under debits if it's positive and 0.0000 under credits the functionality works, but the results are a little difficult to read.

I have tried changing the false declaration to Null, and it works but returns a 1.0000 in the false column. 
Changed it to empty string " ".ToString(), but get a runtime exception.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: I don't know what control you're using or anything, but as for the empty string option, have you tried doing `..., t.Amount.ToString(), "")`? Then they'd resolve to the same type, at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning numbers from your `if(...)` statements and there is no such thing as a blank number. The closest is 0, which is why you see that result. Return strings instead that can show an empty string.

```
Dim query = From t In ds.HNBSavings
            Order By t.Date Descending, t.Id Descending
            Select t.Id, t.Date, t.Desc, Debit = If(t.Amount >= 0, t.Amount.ToString(), ""), Credit = If(t.Amount < 0, t.Amount.ToString(), "")

dgBank.ItemsSource = query.ToList()
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. I had tried this but to the wrong one.